# Count valid/non-NA observations grouped by variable

Tags: r, counting

I have been googling for about two hours now trying to find the solution to a simple problem, but I am not getting anywhere. I am not even finding the right function I could use to get where I want to get, so I have to resort to asking for help even though it seems a very basic question.

I have a survey spanning various countries, and I am in the process of creating a dataframe with statistics derived from the data (such as national mean on a given variable).

Let's say the dataframe df looks like this:

```
country <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
var <- c(1,NA,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,3,4,NA)

df <- cbind.data.frame(country, var)
```

I can easily count the nominal n's:

```
df %>% group_by(country) %>% summarize(n=n())
```

But how do I count valid observations on the variable `var`?

Comment: Could you please share your expected outcome?

Comment: By "count valid observations" do you mean "count the number of values that are not `NA`"? If so, `summarize(non_na_count = sum(!is.na(var)))`

Comment: Put `na.exclude() %>%` before `group_by`.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, I meant to count values that are not NA. Edited the title for clarification. And thanks! I tried to do something with ```is.na```, but since ```table(is.na)```produces the output true-false, I thought I'd have to somehow extract the FALSE count from there. Didn't think of simply trying ```sum```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of these will do it.
Three function calls, `group_by()/summarise()/n()` can be replaced by one only, `count()`.

```r
country <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
var <- c(1,NA,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,3,4,NA)

df <- cbind.data.frame(country, var)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)


df %>% 
  na.exclude() %>%
  count(country)
#>   country n
#> 1       1 5
#> 2       2 5

df %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  count(country) 
#>   country n
#> 1       1 5
#> 2       2 5

df %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>%
  count(country)
#>   country n
#> 1       1 5
#> 2       2 5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>